# a normal k-1 transitive subgroup

Tags: group-theory

I want to show that if G is k-transitive and N is a normal nontrivial subgroup then is K-1 transitive.
I know that I should use the fact G preserve the orbit of N's action of X. so  for some Y on N's action, gY is an orbit of N's action on X.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to show it, because it is not true. For example $S_4$  is $4$-transitive, but has a normal subgroup of order $4$, which is only $1$-transitive.

More generally, for all $n \ge 2$, there is a group ${\rm AGL}(n,2)$ of degree $2^n$ which is $3$-transitive but  has a normal subgroup of order $2^n$ which is only $1$-transitive. (The case $n=2$ gives $S_4$.)

Comment: Thank you. But it is an exersise from book. So I think I can show it. I forgot to mention K>2.

Comment: As I said, $S_4$ is clearly a counterexample with $k=4$, so how can you possibly show it? Exercises in books can be wrong.